# Spring rest call JSON response size from JSON generator

Tags: java, json, spring, stored-procedures, httpresponse

In my project I can't get a direct return statement.

Via JSON generator I can see some methods that set output to JSON string.

I used debug mode to find out the flow:

1. After hitting the URL in postman, backend rest controller gets triggered.
2. Outputstream object from response object (as http request & response both captured by rest controller).
3. Create a output adapter from that response object with help of JSON generator.
4. With adapter, callable statement is created ( JDBC is being used with stored procedure to fetch data from oracle DB.)
5. JSON generator object methods invoked to write as JSON response.

Methods are

`writeOutputParameterStart(stored proc. Result)`

`writeOutputParameterEnds(stored proc. Result)`

I need to find the JSON string.

Is the JSON string created internally by Jackson library? Is there any means I can get the size of that response in JSON?

Comment: Would you have some code to show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically every jsonGenerator object has underlying output stream or writer. So we can invoke getOutputBuffered() method on jsonGenerator object which will return the size of buffered response in int .

So my response size here is 1900 bytes (1.9KB ) which I can directly see in postman page & now I can also print this on log so that a tool SPLUNK can retrieve from server log of my application

NOTE- we should call this method before jsonGenerator is flushed . So once any stream is flushed we can't get buffered data size.